# how to use director class

Tags: coronasdk

hey i'm beginner to corona . i'm confused alot about using director class in my first game and it didnt work.here is one problem which i want to be sort out.how can i insert these to local group????its my first app so please help me.

```
   local tree = {}
   tree[1] = display.newImage( "Palm-arecaceae.png" )
   tree[1].xScale = 0.7; tree[1].yScale = 0.7
   tree[1]:setReferencePoint( display.BottomCenterReferencePoint )
   tree[1].x = 20; tree[1].y = baseline + 40
   tree[1].dx = 0.1
   tree[2] = display.newImage( "Greenhouse-Palm-jubaea01.png" )
   tree[2].xScale = 0.6; tree[2].yScale = 0.6
   tree[2]:setReferencePoint( display.BottomCenterReferencePoint )
   tree[2].x = 120; tree[2].y = baseline + 40
   tree[2].dx = 0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you just have to replace the first line of your code.

```
local tree = {}
```

creates a generic table, DisplayObject are special tables, you can create them using:

`local tree = display.newGroup()`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can create your localgroup and insert them one by one with for like following:

```
local localGroup = display.newGroup()

local tree = {}
tree[1] = display.newImage( "Palm-arecaceae.png" )
tree[1].xScale = 0.7; tree[1].yScale = 0.7
tree[1]:setReferencePoint( display.BottomCenterReferencePoint )
tree[1].x = 20; tree[1].y = baseline + 40
tree[1].dx = 0.1
tree[2] = display.newImage( "Greenhouse-Palm-jubaea01.png" )
tree[2].xScale = 0.6; tree[2].yScale = 0.6
tree[2]:setReferencePoint( display.BottomCenterReferencePoint )
tree[2].x = 120; tree[2].y = baseline + 40
tree[2].dx = 0.2

for i = 1, #tree do
 if(tree[i] ~= nil)then
   localGroup:insert(transTable[i]))          
end
```